# Reduce the differential equation $y= 2px+p^{2}y^{2}$ to Clairaut’s form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Reduce the following differential equation to Clairaut’s form by using the substitution and hence solve:

$y= 2px+p^{2}y^{2}$ where $p={dy\over dx}$

I used $y^{2}=v$ then I get

$v-2p_{1}x + {(x p_{1})^{2}\over v}= ({p_{1}\over2})^{4}$ where $p_{1}={dv\over dx}$

so this is not useful to reduce to Clairaut's form,

please give me a hint to solve this or give me a suitable substitution

Thank you.

Comment: But This problem should be solved by using substitution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a Clairaut equation after some transformation, then its derivative should still factor, modulo the original equation, into a factor containing the second derivative and some other factor for the singular solution. Here you get
$$
y'=2y'+2xy''+2yy'^3+2y^2y'y''
\\
0=(1+2yy'^2)y'+(2x+2y^2y')y''
$$
Now try to remove the higher-degree factors
$$
0=(y+2y^2y'^2)y'^2+2(xy'+y^2y'^2)yy''
\\
0=(y+2(y-2xy'))y'^2+2(xy'+(y-2xy'))yy''
\\
0=(3y-4xy')y'^2+2(y-xy')yy''
$$
There appears to be no way to have the first term to have a non-trivial common factor with the second term. There has to be something wrong with your given task.

---

A simple modification that works with your substitution is
$$
y=2px+yp^2\implies v=v'x+\frac{v'^2}4
$$

Comment: Do you think it is wrong question?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see, the question is wrong. It would be different if the task was to decide if the equation could be reduced to Clairaut form. But the current formulation expresses the certainty that it can be done, and that is not the case.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain your formula? It is not clear to me.

Comment: We know that for a proper Clairaut equation $y=y'x+f(y')$ the derivative factors as $(x+f'(y'))y''=0$. This transfers to the general form, there should be a non-trivial factor without $y''$ in the derivative of the equation. As there is not, it was not originally a Clairaut equation.

Comment: Got it. Thank you